# Why is Kaminari displaying 4 / all records when there is a `limit` being applied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

In Rails console, I do:

```
Video.count
```

Returns 4

```
Video.limit(2)
```

Returns 2

```
v   = Video.limit(2)
vv = v.page(1).per(20).count
```

Returns 4

Why is Kaminari displaying 4 / all records when there is a `limit` being applied? Shouldn't it return 2 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 100 videos in the db and you want to paginate only the first 50 records, lets say 25 per page – as an idea you may limit the number of pages in the view.

```
# videos_controller.rb
def index
  @videos = Video.page(params[:page]).per(25)
end

# index.html.erb
<%= paginate @videos, :num_pages => 2 %>

# index.html.erb using Kaminari 0.14 or higher
<%= paginate @videos, :total_pages => 2 %>
```

In recent versions of Kaminari (>= 0.14), **:num_pages** has been renamed to **:total_pages**. For more information, please refer to https://github.com/errbit/errbit/pull/282 and https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/284.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source code for `per` method you'll see

```
  # Specify the <tt>per_page</tt> value for the preceding <tt>page</tt> scope
  #   Model.page(3).per(10)
  def per(num)
    if (n = num.to_i) <= 0
      self
    else
      limit(n).offset(offset_value / limit_value * n)
    end
  end
```

so your code is something like

```
Video.limit(2).limit(20).count
```

which gives

```
irb(main):002:0* Video.count
=> 4
irb(main):003:0> Video.limit(2).count
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> Video.limit(2).limit(4).count
=> 4
irb(main):005:0> Video.limit(4).limit(10).to_sql 
=> "SELECT TOP (10) [Video].* FROM [Video]"
```

SQL output may be different for different DBMS but `count` should give same values

Comment: Good findings! So lets say I have 100 records in the db. How do I tell Kaminari to paginate, but only for the first 50 records?

Comment: I don't see a way to do it Kaminari uses `limit` so any your custom value will be overridden on pagination. You might use some other gem or implement your own pagination. If you have your values for `page` and `per_page` its quite easy.

Comment: Even will_paginate has the same behaviour. So how would one go about displaying a "Top 50", with pagination. 10 items per page?

Comment: It's the same as displaying all records you just have to delete links to pages with numbers grater than six from rendered HTML. It can be done each time when the pagination is rendered or only if number of records is greater than 50.

Comment: also some filter in action is necessary in case user manually changes page value in URL

Comment: Yea but on the last page, I would still like the pagination to display.. And since we can't limit the pagination items, it will always show pagination link to all items

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

Controller:

```
class Frontend::FirmsController < Frontend::BaseController
  helper_method :max_pages

  def search_with_city
    city = City.find_by_symbol_name(params[:symbol_name])
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if city.nil?
    @firms = Firm.in_city(city.id).page(current_page).per(20)
    render 'index'
  end

  def max_pages
    5
  end

  private

  def current_page
    [(params[:page] || 1).to_i, max_pages].min
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= paginate @firms, total_pages: [@firms.total_pages, max_pages].min %>
```